# HTTP GET request to ArcGIS Notebook Server

Tags: arcpy, request, integration, http, arcgis-notebook

In an external system, I want to make an HTTP GET request —to— ArcGIS Notebooks for Server.

In ArcGIS Notebooks for Server, I would have a Python function that would process the request and return a response.

Is it possible to send an HTTP GET request to ArcGIS Notebook Server?

Comment: Just an observation - you’re kind of bouncing around here with a bunch of similar, but slightly different questions, appearing to take a shot gun approach to Implementing your project. It doesn’t seem like you’ve tried much, nor are you considering what the best approach is. To me it seems you need to have a lengthy discussion instead of these silo’d questions.  Just my 2cents

Comment: @KHimba Yeah, I'm just trying to learn about integrating web GIS. And establish a set of techniques that I can use in future initiatives (the questions don't all pertain to a single requirement). I got tired of not knowing what I was talking about when it comes to web GIS. I'm not a system admin, so I can't test things out properly. All I can do is mock up bits and pieces by using the limited technology I have available to me. The end goal is just to understand what's possible so I can propose half-decent solutions to my team. Cheers.

Comment: @Khimba I don't have access to Portal, ArcGIS Server Manager, or even a proper AGOL account. So, up until about a week ago, I didn't even know what web GIS looked like. I've been poking around a dummy AGOL account and reading the docs. I've come a long way in the past week. As far as I know, though, that's the best approach to learning this stuff. I'm not aware of any books or courses that specifically teach web GIS **integrations**.

Comment: Fair enough. I think you can sign up for a free trial of AGOL. That would give you some things to play with (hosted notebooks)...but right, none of the Enterprise stuff

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution:

Use ArcGIS REST API's  [Execute Notebook](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/enterprise-administration/notebook/execute-notebook.htm) functionality.

> The Execute Notebook operation allows administrators to automate
> notebook execution in their ArcGIS Notebook Server site. The notebook
> specified in the operation will be run with all cells in order.
>
> Using this operation and an external scheduling tool, you can schedule
> the automated execution of a notebook, either once or as a regular
> occurrence.